# My simple Angularjs code does not display results

Tags: angularjs

I am developing a simple AngularJS displaying cities from a module controller.

This is my code:

```
// module:
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


//Service:
    myApp.service('myService', function ($http) {
    this.getCities = function () {
    return $http.get('/City/GetCities');
    }
});

//Controller:
myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope, myService) {
getCitiesList();
function getCitiesList() {
    var getCitiesList = myService.getCities();

    getCitiesList.then(function (emp) {
        $scope.cities = emp.data;

        }, function () { alert('Not Found'); });
    }
});
```

cshtml file:

```
     @{
        ViewBag.Title = "View1";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>View1</h2>
    @section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/angulartest.js"></script>
    }
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myController">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        ID
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in citiesList">
                    <td>
                        {{x.ID_City}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{x.CityName}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I traced the MVC Controller Code. City/GetCities Fires and returns JsonResult but angularjs controller does not display any result And what I get is only this in my browser: Not Found alert.

Comment: console cities inside promise success method...see if it is getting the data correctly... use $ctrl.cities instead of citiesList inside your template code...

Answer (score 0):

In your html you use the variable "citiesList"

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in citiesList">
```

but it has to be "cities" like in your controller

```
$scope.cities = emp.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in citiesList">
```

this

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in cities">
```

and change this service to factory

```
    //Service:
myApp.factory('myService', function ($http) {
    this.getCities = function () {
    return $http.get('/City/GetCities');
    }
});
```

Because service not return anything. 
read this for more info

[service vs factory](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html)

Comment: check in console your emp.data is filled or not?

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: console.log(emp.data);

Comment: I tried this:  getCitiesList.then(function (emp) {
            console.log(emp.data);
            $scope.cities = emp.data;


        }, function () { alert('Not Found'); }); but it fires error function, not success

Comment: read my answer. change your service to factory. I think it should be work.

Answer (score 0):

Your module should look like this

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
```

But you have ended with semi collan(;).

In your service try this

```
  myApp.service('myService', function ($http) {
     var cities = [];
    this.getCities = function () {
     $http.get('/City/GetCities')
       .success(function(emp){
          cities = emp.data;
          return cities;
       })
       .error(function(error){
         alert('invoking error');
        });

    }
});
```

service returns only array so you have declare an empty array and try to return that array in the success call back.

In side your controller

```
  myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope, myService) {


            $scope.citiesList = myService.getCities();
             console.log($scope.citiesList);

});
```

you should declare with $scope variable for citiesList inoder to contact with template.

in your html

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in citiesList">
                    <td>
                        {{x.ID_City}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{x.CityName}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Now this will work.

Comment: this looks like your url is wrong check your url in post man and send the response that can help you